# mouseover, mousemove and hover is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, mouse

Here is my sample code through which I want to display a set of sub applications. I want to display a different set of hard coded values for **Mainapp1** and **Mainapp2**.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="althead" style="border: 0px;width:8%" >MainApp1</th>
    <th class="althead" style="border: 0px;width:7.5%">MainApp2</th>
  </tr>
</table>  


<div class="Not_Editable">Application1</br>
   Application2</br> Application3<br>Application4<br> Application5<br> Application6<br>
</div>
```

And my Javascript is as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   (function (){
     alert("mouse over function");
     $('.althead').mouseover(function (e) {
     alert("mouse over calling");
     $('.Not_Editable').css('top', (e.clientY + 10) + 'px').css('left',  (e.clientX + 10) + 'px').show();

   }).mouseout(function () {
     alert("mouse out");
     $('.Not_Editable').hide();   
   });
})();
```

My CSS is fine and its as below:

```
.Not_Editable {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #292929;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: You are wrapping snippet in a self invoked function, do you want instead to use document ready wrapper instead??? `$(function(){...});`

Comment: Besides, did you attach the jquery file before your script?

Comment: it already works ... see https://jsfiddle.net/jmjtj2wu/

Comment: Thanks. but in my application this is not working. Am i supposed to import/add anything ?

Comment: jQuery is what you need, before your script tag of course, and if possible, place the script at the end of body

Comment: Yes i have jquery, alert("mouse over function"); is being called on load but alert("mouse over calling"); is not alerted at all

Answer (score 0):

Just add the jquery reference in the head section of your code. 
You can use jQuery CDN for online reference.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery and it seems that you don't have jQuery library added to your website.

You can add it by inserting the below code into your html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

BTW, **alert("mouse over function");** is being called because it's a javascript function and does not need jQuery.